# React router - outer html containers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning how to use React Router and have managed to successfully setup my routes. I have a question though with regards to having outer html containers that you want to display across all pages (these containers then have different components that render within them depending what route you are on). Here is my code:

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import siteFeedback from './sections/comments/site-feedback';
import { BrowserRouter,Switch, Route  } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/site-feedback' component={siteFeedback}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**siteFeedback.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class siteFeedback extends Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="outer-container">

                {/* some other code and containers here */}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default siteFeedback;
```

I've simplified my code above as much as possible for sake of clarity. I want the div "outer-container" to wrap every route I have and in my example above its hard coded in the render function of siteFeedback.

My first thought was that "outer-container" div needs to be made into a component itself which could look something like this:

**outer-container.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class outerContainer extends Component { 
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="outer-container">
                {/* the componenets displayed in here would depend on what route you are on*/}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default outerContainer;
```

But the part I am struggling with is the components that would then have to go within the `<div className="outer-container"> </div>`. As this would need to be dynamic depending what page you are on, would I need to pass this down as props somehow?

I see that location is passed down as a prop from the router. Would I need an if statement in my render function of outer-container.js that says something like if route is /siteFeedback then render siteFeedback componenets inside of outer-container?

Looking for advice on the best approach here, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Adding Route to the outer most url

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/' component={outerContainer}/>
    <Route path='/site-feedback' component={siteFeedback}/>
</Switch>
```

and modifying outerContainer as below

```
return (
      <div className="outer-container">
           { this.props.children }
      </div>
)
```

should work.

Comment: hmm, the this.props.children isn't rendering anything, could it be that the props aren't getting passed down for some reason? The outerContainer is showing on all routes however (when I hit / and /site-feedback

Comment: Strange, It should have rendered children component inside. is there any error or import export issues?